# Projects using SymPy?

Tags: sympy

I'm currently learning to use SymPy. It seems interesting and useful, but I haven't had much luck finding out what it's used for in the "real-world".

What scientific/industrial/academic projects are using SymPy?

Comment: If this doesn't get a good response here, it would be a good fit on [scicomp.SE].

Comment: See: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/SymPy-Papers

That page needs to be updated, but at least the quantum papers are really using SymPy.

Comment: @VPeric- Thanks for the link! If you wrote that up as an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: @dcrooney Alright, I've done just that. I'll also try to update the SymPy Papers page itself rather than just list works here, because it will be more useful (disclaimer: I also develop for SymPy occasionally).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some of the uses in academia, you can check the [SymPy Papers](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/SymPy-Papers) page on the SymPy Wiki. The quantum papers in particular use SymPy a lot, mostly because SymPy is used in a quantum physics course on Cal Poly (the professor teaching the course is also a major contributor to SymPy). You can also find some random projects using SymPy with [Google Code Search](https://www.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=%22from%20sympy%20import%22%20lang:%5Epython$%20-github&type=cs), but I couldn't identify any major projects.